# AWS IAM: Exclude fields from response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to define an IAM Policy, so that the `workspaces:DescribeWorkspaces` action does not include the UserName field in the response.

I am not looking for the query/filter parameter, since this is on the client side. I want to restrict the response which is sent to the clients.

How can I do that?

Or, more generally, how can I exclude/include specific fields from a response in the policy definition?